# Unexpected number of rows. improper join?

Tags: sql, impala

I'm stumped on this one. I am a beginner and maybe I have gotten too deep into the joins. As a matter of approach, I wrote queries separately for different functions of the result. I am now trying to combining and it is breaking.

I querying with Impala and created the tables in MySQL before importing into HDFS with HIVE.

The query that works is:

```
SELECT carrier, zone, speed, min_price, price
FROM (SELECT carrier, total_wt, zone, speed, price, MIN(price) OVER(PARTITION BY speed) as min_price
      FROM shipping_prices
      WHERE total_wt IN (
    SELECT
        SUM(prod.shipping_wt)
        FROM order_details ordet
        JOIN products prod
        ON prod.prod_id = ordet.prod_id
        WHERE ordet.order_id = 5841506
        GROUP BY ordet.order_id)
    AND zone IN (
    SELECT cal_zone
      FROM (
        SELECT carrier, dest_zip, origin_zip, zone, MIN(zone) OVER(PARTITION BY carrier) as cal_zone
          FROM shipping_zones
            WHERE (origin_zip = 402 OR origin_zip = 950) AND dest_zip = '560'
          ) t
    WHERE zone=cal_zone)
      ) z
WHERE price=min_price
ORDER BY speed DESC;
```

This returns:

```
+---------+------+-------+-----------+-------+
| carrier | zone | speed | min_price | price |
+---------+------+-------+-----------+-------+
| fedex   | 4    | slow  | 10.86     | 10.86 |
| usps    | 4    | med   | 11.15     | 11.15 |
| usps    | 4    | fast  | 40.55     | 40.55 |
+---------+------+-------+-----------+-------+
```

The query I am having trouble with seems to be failing at the step just before the final result, when it is supposed to find 9 prices total, one for each carrier per level. Instead it returns 27 so it is finding 9 prices per carrier per level. This doesn't make sense as there are only 3 price per carrier per level. Here is the query:

```
SELECT lev5.zone, lev5.cust_id, lev5.total_wt, lev5.zip_shrt, lev5.order_id, lev5.carrier, pric.speed, pric.price, MIN(price) OVER(PARTITION BY speed) as min_price
FROM (
      SELECT lev4.cust_id, lev4.total_wt, lev4.zip_shrt, lev4.order_id, lev4.carrier, lev4.zone
      FROM (
             SELECT lev3.cust_id, lev3.total_wt, lev3.zip_shrt, lev3.order_id, zon.carrier, zon.origin_zip, zon.dest_zip, zon.zone, MIN(zon.zone) OVER(PARTITION BY zon.carrier) as calc_zone
             FROM (
                    SELECT lev2.cust_id, SUM(shipping_wt)/2 AS total_wt, STRLEFT(lev2.zipcode, 3) AS zip_shrt, lev2.order_id
                    FROM (
                           SELECT lev1.zipcode, lev1.cust_id, lev1.order_id, ordet.prod_id
                       FROM (
                          SELECT cus.zipcode, cus.cust_id, ord.order_id
                          FROM orders ord
                          JOIN customers cus ON ord.cust_id = cus.cust_id
                          WHERE ord.order_id = 5841506 
                            ) lev1
                       JOIN order_details ordet
                       ON lev1.order_id = ordet.order_id
                       WHERE ordet.order_id = lev1.order_id
                         ) lev2
                    JOIN products prod
                    ON lev2.prod_id = prod.prod_id
                    GROUP BY lev2.cust_id, zip_shrt, lev2.order_id
                  ) lev3
             JOIN shipping_zones zon
             ON lev3.zip_shrt = zon.dest_zip
             WHERE (origin_zip = 402 OR origin_zip = 950) AND dest_zip = lev3.zip_shrt
           ) lev4
      WHERE lev4.zone = calc_zone
     ) lev5
JOIN shipping_prices pric
ON lev5.zone = pric.zone AND lev5.total_wt = pric.total_wt;
```

This returns:

```
+------+---------+----------+----------+----------+---------+-------+-------------------+-----------+
| zone | cust_id | total_wt | zip_shrt | order_id | carrier | speed | price             | min_price |
+------+---------+----------+----------+----------+---------+-------+-------------------+-----------+
| 4    | 1050349 | 4        | 560      | 5841506  | ups     | med   | 22.24             | 11.15     |
| 4    | 1050349 | 4        | 560      | 5841506  | ups     | med   | 23.57             | 11.15     |
| 4    | 1050349 | 4        | 560      | 5841506  | fedex   | med   | 11.15             | 11.15     |
| 4    | 1050349 | 4        | 560      | 5841506  | ups     | med   | 11.15             | 11.15     |
| 4    | 1050349 | 4        | 560      | 5841506  | usps    | med   | 22.24             | 11.15     |
| 4    | 1050349 | 4        | 560      | 5841506  | fedex   | med   | 23.57             | 11.15     |
| 4    | 1050349 | 4        | 560      | 5841506  | usps    | med   | 23.57             | 11.15     |
| 4    | 1050349 | 4        | 560      | 5841506  | usps    | med   | 11.15             | 11.15     |
| 4    | 1050349 | 4        | 560      | 5841506  | fedex   | med   | 22.24             | 11.15     |
| 4    | 1050349 | 4        | 560      | 5841506  | fedex   | slow  | 11.15             | 10.86     |
| 4    | 1050349 | 4        | 560      | 5841506  | fedex   | slow  | 11.15             | 10.86     |
| 4    | 1050349 | 4        | 560      | 5841506  | fedex   | slow  | 10.86             | 10.86     |
| 4    | 1050349 | 4        | 560      | 5841506  | usps    | slow  | 11.15             | 10.86     |
| 4    | 1050349 | 4        | 560      | 5841506  | usps    | slow  | 11.15             | 10.86     |
| 4    | 1050349 | 4        | 560      | 5841506  | usps    | slow  | 10.86             | 10.86     |
| 4    | 1050349 | 4        | 560      | 5841506  | ups     | slow  | 11.15             | 10.86     |
| 4    | 1050349 | 4        | 560      | 5841506  | ups     | slow  | 11.15             | 10.86     |
| 4    | 1050349 | 4        | 560      | 5841506  | ups     | slow  | 10.86             | 10.86     |
| 4    | 1050349 | 4        | 560      | 5841506  | ups     | fast  | 69.93000000000001 | 40.55     |
| 4    | 1050349 | 4        | 560      | 5841506  | ups     | fast  | 40.55             | 40.55     |
| 4    | 1050349 | 4        | 560      | 5841506  | ups     | fast  | 65.94             | 40.55     |
| 4    | 1050349 | 4        | 560      | 5841506  | usps    | fast  | 69.93000000000001 | 40.55     |
| 4    | 1050349 | 4        | 560      | 5841506  | usps    | fast  | 40.55             | 40.55     |
| 4    | 1050349 | 4        | 560      | 5841506  | usps    | fast  | 65.94             | 40.55     |
| 4    | 1050349 | 4        | 560      | 5841506  | fedex   | fast  | 69.93000000000001 | 40.55     |
| 4    | 1050349 | 4        | 560      | 5841506  | fedex   | fast  | 40.55             | 40.55     |
| 4    | 1050349 | 4        | 560      | 5841506  | fedex   | fast  | 65.94             | 40.55     |
+------+---------+----------+----------+----------+---------+-------+-------------------+-----------+
```

I went into excel to confirm (source data for shipping_prices) and did a COUNTIFS function and it only returned 9 rows, as it should.

I would really appreciate some help. I've really been trying to solve it on my own but maybe it is my lack of knowledge of joins or something else I don't have the experience to spot. I'm really proud of myself that I've gotten to this point, but this road block is killing me.

Thank you

Comment: what is your expected result? give us sample data as well. thanks.

Comment: the expected result is the first table I posted. The sample data is large I don't think I have enough space to post all details about the source tables. what else can I do to clarify?

Comment: so why do you need to change the working sql?

Comment: That working query is just a part of a larger query (which I'm having trouble with). They are written slightly different and I have tried to do it properly through join in the larger query but it broke something in the process. When I talk through them semantically out loud they seem the same to me, but obviously not. this is where I'm stuck.

Comment: Looking at the query, the first thing I would do is cut down on the sub-selects. They just make the end-result confusing and process-heavy. Think of the data that you want to get to in the sets that you need to have, then find out the commonalities of the sets and how you can use one set to filter out the next set or how to combine them. I think if you take your query above and work through it without making individual query pieces, you'll find where it's duplicating. Plus, your query will run tons faster.

Comment: Thank you for that helpful and insightful comment. I'm pretty new to SQL and I thought the method I was doing is best practice. Clearly not. Could you explain a bit more the alternative method you are suggesting? The way I have it now seems very logical as each "level" passes information on to the next. Feel free to post it as an answer. Maybe structure is my problem.

Comment: In your first query you look for the carriers that offer the minimum shipping prices per speed for the given order weight. What I don't understand is the zone part. You make sure that there is a shipping zone matching the zip codes, but you don't care about the carrier. Shouldn't this match the shipping_prices.carrier? And then a lesser zone is the better zone? I find this somewhat hard to grasp.

Comment: As to your second query: When you filter price = min_price, then you are back to 9 rows. Is this what you want?

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why do you divide `SUM(prod.shipping_wt)` by 2?

Comment: By the way: Your queries are not bad and you have reason enough to be proud of them. The idea to select the first thing and then based on this the second and so on is not too bad. It even helps avoiding possible errors (especially by aggregating before joining) and is even needed when using `MIN/MAX OVER` to get the best matches. Only when done so excessively it gets hard to read. In the inner queries all you do is join your orders with their customer and their order details and products. This can be done with simple joins and will be easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you for the comments @ThorstenKettner, I'm sorry for the delay in getting back to you. Finals slammed me and I didn't get some free time until now (spring break!). I have posted the answer below along with answers to your questions. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up with that gives me the expected result:

```
SELECT lev6.order_id, lev6.carrier, lev6.speed, lev6.min_price AS cheapest_price
FROM (
SELECT lev5.zone, lev5.cust_id, lev5.total_wt, lev5.zip_shrt, lev5.order_id, lev5.origin_zip, lev5.carrier, pric.speed, pric.price, MIN(pric.price) OVER(PARTITION BY speed) as min_price
FROM (
      SELECT lev4.cust_id, lev4.total_wt, lev4.zip_shrt, lev4.order_id, lev4.carrier, lev4.zone, lev4.origin_zip
      FROM (
             SELECT lev3.cust_id, lev3.total_wt, lev3.zip_shrt, lev3.order_id, zon.carrier, zon.origin_zip, zon.dest_zip, zon.zone, MIN(zon.zone) OVER(PARTITION BY zon.carrier) as calc_zone
             FROM (
                    SELECT lev2.cust_id, SUM(shipping_wt)/2 AS total_wt, STRLEFT(lev2.zipcode, 3) AS zip_shrt, lev2.order_id
                    FROM (
                           SELECT lev1.zipcode, lev1.cust_id, lev1.order_id, ordet.prod_id
                       FROM (
                          SELECT cus.zipcode, cus.cust_id, ord.order_id
                          FROM orders ord
                          JOIN customers cus ON ord.cust_id = cus.cust_id
                          WHERE ord.order_id = 6453746
                            ) lev1
                       JOIN order_details ordet
                       ON lev1.order_id = ordet.order_id
                       WHERE ordet.order_id = lev1.order_id
                         ) lev2
                    JOIN products prod
                    ON lev2.prod_id = prod.prod_id
                    GROUP BY lev2.cust_id, zip_shrt, lev2.order_id
                  ) lev3
             JOIN shipping_zones zon
             ON lev3.zip_shrt = zon.dest_zip
             WHERE (origin_zip = 402 OR origin_zip = 950) AND dest_zip = lev3.zip_shrt
           ) lev4
      WHERE lev4.zone = calc_zone
     ) lev5
JOIN shipping_prices pric
ON lev5.zone = pric.zone AND lev5.total_wt = pric.total_wt
WHERE lev5.carrier = pric.carrier
) lev6
WHERE lev6.price = lev6.min_price
ORDER BY lev6.speed DESC;
```

My problem was I didn't have a WHERE condition on my lev5. I added:

```
WHERE lev5.carrier = pric.carrier
```

This eliminated the duplicates and properly returned only 9 shipping prices, 3 from each carrier (slow, med, fast). I then added lev6 to only return the lowest price per speed.

@Thorsten Kettner as for why I had to divide the sum of the product's weights by 2, unfortunately I don't have an answer. If I don't it returns double the actual weight for the order, not sure why.

This query is not bullet proof and hasn't been tested for nulls and all situations (like when two prices are equal at the same speed) but it was good enough for what I wanted to do and demonstrate a proof of concept.